# Escape &apos; in html

Tags: html

I want to give a guide to my visitor. If they want to write ' (apostrophe), they should write `&apos;` . How to show `&apos;` in html ? (Bcz it shows `'` automatically)

Comment: Why should anybody do this on their own? Can't you run this transformation automatically?

Comment: i've tried `htmlentities` but it doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a pretty broad error description. Why do you expect that `htmlentities` replaces a single quote?

Comment: thankyou, I've found it and works well for me. `htmlentities("&apos;")`

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML entities like this:

```html
&amp;apos&semi;
```